# How to set the default branch in GitHub.com?

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository

I found the following info, but didn't find where to go to access it. Didn't find it in account settings. Is there a repo settings page? Do you have to be the repo owner?

https://github.com/blog/421-pick-your-default-branch

How to set the default branch on **github.com** when I go to browse commits.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Do you have to be the repo owner?

Yes you do.

> How to set the default branch on github.com when I go to browse commits.

If you fork the repository, you can change the default branch of **your** fork, by clicking on the **Settings** button (see below).

This will allow you to pick your favorite branch as the default one for your own fork, but you'll have to keep your forked repository in sync with the upstream repository by yourself.

[image: settings]

Or you can directly jump to the following url `https://github.com/{:user}/{:repo}/settings`

Comment: That's probably why I didn't find it.

Comment: This answer appears to be outdated.

Answer (score 17):

### **2021 Update**

The current GitHub UI has changed quite a bit -- what used to be buttons are now tabs across the top of the repo's home page:

[image: current default branch is 1.8]

Click the Settings tab then, on the left, click Branches:

[image: Branches option]

Mousing over the switch branch icon (right/left arrow, bottom right of pic) pops up a hint. [or click the pencil icon to give the default branch a new name]:

[image: mousing over switch branch icon]

Clicking on switch branch pops up a list of branches:

[image: branch list]

Select the new default branch (I chose master), click Update, and acknowledge that you know what you're doing:

[image: acknowledge new default]

Voila!

[image: master is new default branch]

Answer (score 14):

Just log into your GitHub account and on the far right side in the navigation menu choose **Settings**, in the **Settings Tab** choose **Default Branch** and return back to main page of your repository.

Here's a visual for the answer:

[image]

Comment: How does returning back to the main page contribute to changing the default branch?

Answer (score 2):

2023 Update

It has now moved to the "General" section of the settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Initially, I confirmed the "Default Branch" was 'master' even though clones were defaulting to another branch 'stackato'.   Here's what I tried...

**Change and change back**

1. The main/top option in the settings is titled "Options" and I changed my "Default Branch" from 'master' (what I wanted) to a third branch name that I did not want, but different from 'stackato' that was appearing when I cloned
2. I selected "Collaborators" from the menu on the left
3. I selected "Options" again from the menu on the left and confirmed that my selection from #1 was still active (telling me it had presumably auto-saved)
4. I changed my "Default Branch" back to 'master'
5. I selected "Collaborators" again from the menu on the left
6. I selected "Options" one last time from the menu on the left and confirmed that my 'master' was still active (telling me it had presumably auto-saved)

**and/or Wait a while**

I cannot rule out the possibility that it just took some time for my change to 'propagate'.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy from the github interface. You just need to go into the repository where you want to change de default branch and click on settings on the right side of the page:

[image]

and then, inside there you just need to change the branch as you would like to:

[image]