# How to rename main branch to master on a Github repository

Tags: git, github

I'd like to create a github repository and rename the `main` branch to `master`.

If I create a new repository on github and do

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M master
```

I get

```
error: refname refs/heads/master not found
fatal: Branch rename failed
```

so I seem to somehow not understand git well enough. What's the issue here?

---

I must have gotten confused when I was playing around with the above. The following happens:

`git init` create the repository

`git add README.md` adds the file

`git commit -m "first commit"` adds the file to the `master` branch since that still default for git

so I never have to rename it in the first place. Now Github uses the default main, which can be [changed in settings -> repositories on github.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66038734/55246)

Comment: If you want to rename  **git branch -M <oldname> <newname>** or rename current branch **git branch -M <newname>**

Comment: @Rahul OP seems to already be doing that?

Comment: If the repo was created on github then why does the example include “git init”?

Comment: Currently in detached head state. Try to checkout a new branch to associate it with the current commit:

Comment: @evolutionxbox What do you mean? You still have to init the repo locally.

Comment: Not if it's created on github. The repo can cloned.

Comment: Ah yeah sure you can clone it but that's not my workflow. It's not even the official workflow. Good input though.

Comment: I solved my problem. I'll add an edit.

Comment: @handy I can understand if it’s not your workflow, but what is “official workflow”?

Comment: @evolutionxbox With "official workflow" I basically meant their instructions. If you create an empty repository on github it doesn't tell you to clone it but gives you instructions on how to create the repository locally and just add the remote manually. It doesn't really matter in the end.

Comment: Wokism is a cancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `README.md` doesn't actually exist, `git checkout -B master` will do what you want.  `git branch -M` is expecting a full ref that actually refers to something, not the stub `git init` (or `git checkout --orphan`) creates. I'd agree it "should" handle this case, whether it's worth a patch is up to anybody capable of writing a good one.   Shouldn't be *too* hard.

My test case that led to this answer was simply running your commands in an empty directory; that produced your reported symptom. Running them in a directory that (already) includes a `README.md` works the way you want, i.e. doesn't produce that error.  Did you perhaps expect `git init` to create a default `README.md`?

Comment: I did not expect `git init` to create `README-md`. I didn't realize that there was basically no branch present until one actually commits something. So it boils down to having a misunderstanding of some of the functionality of git.

Comment: git checkout -B main is the answer then?

Answer (score 28):

Using the `-m` option (move/rename) instead of `-M` with the name of the branch you're renaming from, here `main`, will work. Then you can push your renamed branch and maintain your reflog as well.

```
git branch -m main master
git push -u origin master
```

I also wrote a blog post with more details which can in case the repo was cloned by someone else before renaming the branch. [You can check it out here.](https://www.codingnagger.com/2021/09/26/easily-rename-your-git-default-branch-from-main-to-master/)

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this in Azure DevOps. It should be the same on GitHub.

Run these lines in your terminal at the project root.

```py
git branch -m main master
git push -u origin master
git push origin --delete main
```

Then I set `master` as the default branch.