# There isn’t anything to compare. main and master are entirely different commit histories

Tags: git, github, git-branch, pull-request

I have these:

```
(fashcomp) [jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git push --set-upstream origin master
Counting objects: 50, done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (45/45), done.
Writing objects: 100% (50/50), 22.72 MiB | 8.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 50 (delta 16), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: 
remote: Create a pull request for 'master' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/monajalal/fashion_compatibility/pull/new/master
remote: 
To https://github.com/monajalal/fashion_compatibility.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch master set up to track remote branch master from origin.

(fashcomp) [jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git branch -a
* master
  remotes/origin/master

(fashcomp) [jalal@goku fashion-compatibility]$ git fetch --all --tags
Fetching origin
```

and i see:
[image]

and:
[image]

However, I don't see any place for requesting. How can I make master the actual branch that has the code and get rid of main?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Given that `main` branch wasn't showing in terminal, using the GitHub UI did the trick for me.

> Settings --> Branches --> Default Branch --> Change to the intended
> branch

Credits to https://stackoverflow.com/a/14551480/2414957

Comment: If the question was answered by reading a different question, delete _your_ question, as it contributes nothing to the mix, and anyway you are now effectively just duplicating your own (edited) answer on the other question.