# Github default branch

Tags: git, github, git-push

Help me please ,i pushed my project to GitHub(branch master).But in my repo i have 2 branches:

1)Default branch(main)

2)My branch(master)

[image]

[image]

What is **"default branch"** ? How can i delete it?

Comment: [Changing the default branch](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the default branch in GitHub.com?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334045/how-to-set-the-default-branch-in-github-com)

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález partly yes,i switched it,but why i have 2 branches instead of master(that i pushed)?

Comment: You have two branches because you told GitHub to make one branch with one commit on it when you had GitHub make the repository. You chose to make the `main` branch at that time.

Comment: @torek so,how to fix it?And how to avoid this situation in the future?

Comment: If you don't want a branch named `main`, delete it (note that this will throw out the one commit GitHub made for you, though it's the same standard default one they always make depending on which clicky boxes you tick). Note that you'll first have to use the "set default branch in GitHub" thing first, to set the default branch to the other branch you made, `master`, with your `git push`.

Comment: To avoid this in the future, when using the GitHub web interface to create a new repository, select the "create empty repository" option. You'll *still* need to set the default branch if you want something other than `main` as the default, as the default branch setting happens during repository creation, and then stays that way until you change it.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this in the future, when using the GitHub web interface to create a new repository, select the "create empty repository" option. You'll still need to set the default branch if you want something other than main as the default, as the default branch setting happens during repository creation, and then stays that way until you change it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).